# Bootstrap-Multiselect: how to get both features of optionClass and includeSelectAllOption

Tags: multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I was following the [Bootstrap Multiselect documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-optionClass) to implement bootstrap multiselect. However I want to get both the effects of `optionClass` and `includeSelectAllOption` so that I get select all and alternate coloring. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-optionClass').multiselect({
            
            optionClass: function(element) {
                var value = $(element).val();
 
                if (value%2 == 0) {
                    return 'even';
                }
                else {
                    return 'odd';
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #example-optionClass-container .multiselect-container li.odd {
        background: #eeeeee;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap Multiselect Test</h2>
  <p>I want to use both <b>optionClass</b> and <b>includeSelectAllOption</b> togather:</p>            
  <div id="example-optionClass-container">
    <select id="example-optionClass" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please Help me to get both of their effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the `includeSelectAllOption`, this looks as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-optionClass').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true, // add select all option as usual
            optionClass: function(element) {
                var value = $(element).val();
 
                if (value%2 == 0) {
                    return 'even';
                }
                else {
                    return 'odd';
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #example-optionClass-container .multiselect-container li.odd {
        background: #eeeeee;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap Multiselect Test</h2>
  <p>I want to use both <b>optionClass</b> and <b>includeSelectAllOption</b> togather:</p>            
  <div id="example-optionClass-container">
    <select id="example-optionClass" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to take into account the select all option in your coloring, i.e. treat the select all option as `odd` (as the first option), you can reverse the coloring and manipulate the `multiselect-all` class:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-optionClass').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true, // add select all option as usual
            optionClass: function(element) {
                var value = $(element).val();
 
                if (value%2 == 0) {
                    return 'odd'; // reversed
                }
                else {
                    return 'even'; // reversed
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #example-optionClass-container .multiselect-container li.odd {
        background: #eeeeee;
    }
    #example-optionClass-container .multiselect-all {
       background: #eeeeee;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap Multiselect Test</h2>
  <p>I want to use both <b>optionClass</b> and <b>includeSelectAllOption</b> togather:</p>            
  <div id="example-optionClass-container">
    <select id="example-optionClass" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```